# What is this 2' high plant with curved spikes of white flowers, growing in eastern Massachusetts?

Tags: identification, flowers, perennials

Please identify this plant. It is about two feet tall and thriving in the shade of large trees near the edge of a small street.[image]

Comment: This is one of my favorite perennials.  Yours look very happy.  It is a cousin of one of the top ten most badest weeds, grin.  Seriously.  You shouldn't worry.  Just in case you'd like to confine these to certain beds cut off the flower spikes before they go to seed.

Comment: @stormy out of curiosity, what is the 'most badest' weed you were referring to?

Comment: Purple Loosestrife, Lythrum salicaria or virgatum.

Answer (score 4):

That is [Gooseneck Loosestrife, *Lysimachia clethroides*](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=e100). The common name comes from the shape of the flower spike, which somewhat resembles a goose's neck curve.